# get the object value using ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am new to Javascript and rails so please consider that I am not really good at this. I have basic ajax calls

**ajax:**

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "/url",
  data: $('#somedata').serialize(),
  success: function(response){

    for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        $('#something').append(response[i].name);
         }
  },
```

**controller(action)**

```
  def random_action
    @obj = Model.all
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json {render json: @obj.pluck(:name).to_json}
        format.html
      end
    end
```

**view:**

```
 <li id="something"></li>
```

When I checked the console, it grabs some data but it displays like

```
[{"id:1","name:something"},{"id:2","name:okay"}]
```

and what I need is the **name** only so I was gonna try something append the name only in my html view.

somehow like that, so that the `<li>` tag has the name of the data. please help me guys:(

Comment: add name in data attribute, check https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Respond only with the names:

```
render json: @obj.pluck(:name).to_json
```

or 2) iterate over elements in javascript callback and call element.name

```
for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  $('#something').append(response[i].name);
}
```

EDIT: changed for/in to for(i....i++) syntax, changed "elements" to "response", since "elements" is a string, "response" is actually the array

EDIT3: I'll update the answer since the question changes in the comments. I'll try to explain it a little bit.

First you need to understand that "@obj" is a really bad name for a variable and what you have there is not an object but a collection of objects because you are doing "Model.all". Maybe you can call it @objects or a more descriptive word.

Then, when you do @objects.pluck(:name), it returns an array with the name of each record. Now that you want more attributes you can do pluck(:name, :age) and it will return an array of array pairs where position 0 is name and position 1 is age.

You could just do to_json to that array and respond with the result, but I'd suggest to make it a little more easy to use transforming it to an array of hashes before calling to_json:

```
@objects.pluck(:name, :age).map{|arr| {name: arr[0], age: arr[1]}}
```

Now you have an array of hashes and you will be able to do "element.name" or "element.age" within the javascript callback.

Summing up, you will do

```
render json: @objects.pluck(:name, :age).map{|arr| {name: arr[0], age: arr[1]}}.to_json
```

and your javascript for loop will be

```
for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  name = response[i].name;
  age = response[i].age;
  // do something with those values, add li elements, whatever you want
}
```

Comment: not good practice to use `for in` on arrays and `element` in loop will actully be index not the object

Comment: @charlietfl you are right, I was mixing objects and arrays and coffee script in my head, I'll update the answer, thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tested the first one and it worked like charm. Thanks a lot but quick question. If I want to display one by one. For example, if `@obj` has 3 values and I want them to be displayed one by one in that case, should I use the second one like you said? `for element in elements` one

Comment: because when I added that in my javascript code it makes an error such as `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: @Jay You need to loop through the elements while appending. You can checkout my answer for reference. Also, if you need just the names to be sent in the response, use `.select(:name)` instead of `.all` and looping through records for returning just the names.

Comment: for/in is not right for arrays like @charlietfl pointed out, i've edited the syntax

Comment: @arieljuod man I feel almost there and feel very close to make it work but unfortunately, it displays nothing. I edited my code like your suggestion. could you please have a look ?

Comment: it'd recommend you to use the browser's inspector to debug this, put a debugger; line in the script and open your browser's dev tools and the execution should stop on that debugger; line and you can inspect variables and all

Comment: @arieljuod I appreciate your help. I have tried this way (without the `name`) `$('#something').append(response[i]);` and it shows like **- name1name2**. For example, if the object title were **name1**, **name2** those are displaying in a line. but it should be something like **-name1**, **-name2**. At the moment I added `+ '<br>'` but this is not the correct way to do. right?

Comment: You should have an ul element with id=something and append li elements. $('#something').append($('<li />').text(response[i]));

Comment: @arieljuod Man, It works just like sooooooooo beautiful! thx a lot !!!!!!

Comment: @arieljuod Man, there is an additional question. If I want to return multiple objects. I have tried `format.json  { render :json => {:name => @obj.pluck(:name), 
                                        :age => @obj_age }}`. but seems does not work. can you please tell me whats the correct way?

Comment: I saw that las comment late, I've added a better explanation of each method cause I think you are missing some important concepts of the code, just to make it clear what each line does so you can extend or change it easier

Answer (score 0):

You could something like this:

```
@objects = Model.select(:name)
```

What this does is it returns a collections of records with just `name` values.

Define a `div` with an ID in your HTML.

```
<div id='links' />
```

In your JS file you can do this:

```
var div = $("div#links")    
elements.map((element) => div.append('<li>' + element.name + '</li>'));
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: If you want to skip the loop on the collection, you should use Model.pluck(:name), it returns just an array of strings.

Comment: Thanks for your help!